# How do I push nested array values to a mongodb document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

If I have a document in mongodb with this structure:

```
{
    "_id": "user1",
    "loc": [
        {
            "lon": 51.12076493195686,
            "lat": -113.98040771484375
        },
        {
            "lon": 51.10682735591432,
            "lat": -114.11773681640625
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I be able to push a new array containing lon and lat within the loc list?

The structure I am trying to use is this: `db.collection('location').update({_id:'user1'},{'$push': {"lat": "-107.10400390625", "lon": "33.32343323432" }})`

This obviously does not work because the lat and lon are nested within loc.

Comment: I can't try it myself at the moment, but on my opinion only the 'loc' is missing after $push:

Comment: Yes I added it: db.collection('location').update({_id:'user1'},{"$push": { loc: {lon: 69.09144802136697, lat: -107.10400390625 }}})

This works...thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.collection('location').update({_id:'user1'},{'$push': { "loc": {"lat": "-107.10400390625", "lon": "33.32343323432" }}})
```